# (Chrome Extension) Can't pass message from background.js to popup.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I don't receive the alert that should show up when my popup script receives a message.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Drill Sergeant",
  "description": "Tracks time spent on 'watchlist' websites",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
  "web_accessible_resources": ["background.js"],
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "webNavigation", "notifications", "tabs"]
}
```

Inclusion of popup.js in my html file:

```
<body>
     ....
    <script src = popup.js></script>

</body>
```

Message call from background:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab)
{
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    text: "please work"
  });
   checkMe();
});
```

popup.js code:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        alert("PLEASE WORK");
        console.log("PLEASE WORK");
    }
);
```

The checkMe() function executes whenever I change a page (I know because it has debug alerts too), but I don't get the alert from my popup.js... I've looked at other threads and I've used runtime.onMessage instead of tabs.onMessage, but it still doesn't work. Thanks for the help

Comment: The popup doesn't run when it's hidden so it won't receive the message. Depending on what you want to achieve, there's probably no need for messaging at all.

Comment: That explains everything, thanks!